# "I am on imperial business and may not be interfered with..."

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

In the TV-series, "I Claudius" (BBC, 1976), episode 6, Drusus (Son of Emperor Tiberius, nicknamed, "Castor") stops a prefect, in the street, who was arresting one of his friends. The haughty official said:

> "I am on imperial business and may not be interfered with, not even by the son of the Emperor!".

In an attempt to translate this, is it the verb: "negotior imperii"--"I do the business of the empire"; or, the noun: "negotium imperii ago"? In Lewis & Short the verb seems to be used e.g. "to do business with [someone]".

The "interfere" part is approached with an jussive, passive, present subjunctive giving:

> "negotium imperii ago et non intercedar ne filio quidem Caesaris!"

Is this correct?

---

Thanks to Tyler & Joonas for comments. How about:

> "negotio imperii fungor et non impediar ne filio quidem Caesaris!"

Comment: There are different ways to say this, but the pertinent verb is "impedior".

Comment: I think *fungor* with ablative is going to be better than *ago* with accusative.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: There are exs., from early Latin, of "fungor" taking the accusative: "tu tibi istos habeas tutures piscis, avis, sine me alioto fungi fortunas meas."--"You just keep those swabs of yours and your fish and your game for yourself, and leave me to my garlic and my lot," (Plaut. Most. 45). I haven't seen "tu tibi istos" altogether before! This, from the 3rd.C BC.

Comment: @tony True, the accusative seems possible too. My main point was that *agere* doesn't fit the job nearly as well as *fungi*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

- Use *fungi* instead of *agere*. (This you did in your revised attempt.)
- Use an adjective like in English. *Imperiale* is better than *imperii*.
- I think the second part works better when phrased more along the lines of "and nobody can interfere". There are many ways to go about this, including the use of *quis* as "anyone".
- When using *ne...quidem*, put the most emphatic word in between. It's not "Caesar's not even a son" but "son of not even Caesar".

My suggestion would be this, and I emphasize that it is not the one and best solution:

> Negotio imperiali fungor nemoque impedire potest, ne Caesaris quidem filius!

My thinking here is that nobody would be physically able to resist.
If it is about not being allowed rather than being unable, switch from *impedire* to *licet*:

> Negotio imperiali fungor neminique impedire licet, ne Caesaris quidem filio!

You might well replace *negotio* by *munere*.
I would be tempted to do so, but nuances like this depend on context.

Comment: Maybe use licet instead of potest? This sounds to me like it's saying that it's impossible for anyone to interfere.

Comment: @TKR Good point! I took the original as meaning that nobody would be physically able to resist, so I went with a stronger wording. I added a note on that and a second formulation option with *licere* at the end.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Thank you. You have used the adjective!! In my very first attempt at this I wrote, "rem imperialem facio..."--"I'm doing/on imperial business..."; then, thinking about e.g. "his friend", expreesed with a genitive, "amicus eius"--"friend of him", I plumped for genitive-of-noun, "imperii".

Comment: @tony As a broad rule, I would say that Latin uses an adjective rather than a genitive more often than English whenever such an adjective exists. In some situations there's no adjective (like your *eius*). The verb *facio* doesn't work either. I haven't thought of anything better than *fungor*. The *negotium* could well be *munus* instead.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Georges has no better ideas than *res, negotium* and *causa*. *Res* is boring and *causa* too suggestive of legal proceedings, so I think *negotium* really fits best here.